# Convert a set to a set in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I'd like to write a function that will convert:

```
 (#{"one" "two"})
```

to

```
#{"one" "two"}
```

I am doing this because I have a function that returns (#{"one" "two"}) as the result of a for loop.  I'd like to take that resulting set and compare it with another by using  clojure.set/difference.  I can't because one of them has a set of parenthesis around it.

Thank you!

Comment: If you were asking how to convert `'("one" "two")` to `#{"one" "two"}`, that would make sense. But with `(#{"one" "two"})` you *already have* a set, which is inside a seq of length one. Your question doesn't make sense without clarification in that case.

Comment: Thank for the feedback.  I've re written the question if you wouldn't mind taking another look!

Comment: I was under the impression that a for loop will always return a lazy expression.  Am I missing something here? http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/for

Comment: (clojure.set/difference (#{"one" "two"}) #{"one"}) results in ArityException Wrong number of args (0) passed to: PersistentHashSet  clojure.lang.AFn.throwArity (AFn.java:437)  but (clojure.set/difference #{"one" "two"} #{"one"}) results in #{"two"}.  They are not evaluated the same.

Comment: @user3245240, [`for`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/for) is not a loop in Clojure. It is a list comprehension.

Comment: @user3245240, if you want a for comprehension's results to be put into a set, you should be doing that after and outside of the comprehension, not within it. For instance, `(into #{} (for ...))` would do the Right Thing if your comprehension generated `"one"` and `"two"`. Whatever you're doing here is having significant complexity overhead and performance cost vs the idiomatic approach.

Comment: ...moreover, even if you were calling something within the comprehension that's returning sets (and don't have an option to do otherwise -- which is a design smell; indicates that concerns have been complected), you can trivially iterate over them and expose their contents by adding another layer, making your output ready for `into`. `(into #{} (for [some-set (get-sets) item some-set] item))`

Comment: alternately, if your comprehension (and again, don't call it a "loop" -- it's not) is guaranteed to only return a single item, just pass its result to `first`.

Comment: That set/difference call is broken because indeed they are not evaluated the same. Parens are not a grouping construct in Clojure, they are used to call functions, or construct literal lists. We don't have grouping constructs because our syntax does not allow precedence ambiguity.

Comment: `(clojure.set/difference (first '(#{"one" "two"})) #{"one"})` seems to do what you want. When writing this using literals the seq enclosing the first set must be quoted so it's not treated as a form and executed. Share and enjoy.

Comment: Bob how would I turn (#{"one" "two"}) into '(#{"one" "two"})? I can't just put a ' in front of it because its the return value from another function.

Comment: Charles and Bob... what if it wasn't the first or last element?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that:

- the input of the desired function is a lazy seq (or some other sequence) containing exactly one set
- the output of the function should be the set

There already exists a function that does what you want: `first`. You can read about it [here](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/first).

Comment: Can you tell me how you are binding (#{"one" "two"}) to a? When I call (first a) I get back "one".

Comment: Please disregard my answer above. I realized that I need more information to answer your question. What does your first function return? Always a set? What does your second function return? Always a sequence containing exactly one set? What should your result be? "I just one to take the result of the first function and remove it from the result of the second." is not accurate enough. Can you provide several examples?

Comment: I think I was asking too big of a question, so I broke the question down to the most important part.  I edited the original question; thanks!

Comment: @user3245240, if `a` was `(#{"one" "two" })`, not `#{"one" "two"}`, `(first a)` would return `#{"one" "two"}`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that what you have in your example is a lazy seq of sets like:

```
(def data '(#{"one" "two"} #{"three"} #{"one"})); note the quote
```

Depending on your requirements you may want:

Remove from all the sets the element "one":

```
   user> (map #(disj % "one") data)       
   (#{"two"} #{"three"} #{})
```

Remove all sets that have the word "one":

```
   user> (remove #(% "one") data)
   (#{"three"})
```

Convert the seq of sets into just one set and remove the element "one"

```
   user> (disj (set (apply concat data)) "one")
   #{"two" "three"}
```

Remove from the first set of the seq the element "one"

```
   user> (disj (first data) "one")
   #{"two"}
   user> (seq (disj (first data) "one")) ; this returns exactly what you ask for
   ("two")
```

Comment: for the new version of your question, `(set (apply concat data))` is probably what you are looking for. I wrote than all those options because you were using `remove` in the wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

```
(clojure.set/difference (first '(#{"one" "two"})) #{"one"})
```

... produces `#{"two"}`

You can pull out the expression into a function and apply it thus:

```
((fn [x y] (clojure.set/difference (first x)) y) '(#{"one" "two"}) #{"one"})
```